# What is this leaf vegetable with thin pale green stalks and mid-green leaves?

Tags: identification, brassicas, leaf-vegetables

I thought I planted the Asian vegetable seed bok choy but what is coming out from the ground does not look like bok choy? Do you know what it is?

[image: Asian green]

Comment: Audrey, welcome to the site! Why do you think it's not bok choi?

Comment: Hey thanks Stephie. I don't think it's bok choy because this veggie doesn't have thick white stems. Its stems are very thin and all green. What do you think it is?

Comment: Hard to say. But the stalks *may* thicken later - I guess there are a few breeds on the market, some of the super-thick variety, some more "leggy". I think the ones pictued in [this blog](http://suburbansustainability.com/tag/seedlings/) (halfway down the page) might be roughly the same age as your seedlings. I haven't grown enough cabbage varieties to venture an answer here, though. You might consider edting your comment into your question (or I could do this for you), making the question "better" (= upvotes) according to this site's standards ;-)

Comment: What did your seed packet say? Was there a picture? Apparently bok choy (brassica rappa varieties) comes in [green and white and with thin or thick stalks](http://www.rareseeds.com/store/vegetables/bok-choy/). You might *have* bok choy, after all, just not the breed you were expecting...

Comment: Thanks Stephie for your comments. I didn't buy the seeds. They were given to me. I just assumed that it is the thick white stem variety which I'm more familiar with :) I had a look at the types of bok choy through the link you sent through and mine looks rather like the Shanghai Green variety. I'm quite happy with that. Thank you so much for sharing the information. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like an *Amaranthaceae*, maybe a *Betta sp.* (*vulgaris, etc*...).

Comment: Hi, it is noticed, I'll give more informations next time. But normally with the scientific name (i.e. the latin name, which as to be in italic), anyone can have all the information needed very easily on the internet...

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for your comment. Someone did suggest to me that it could be a type of chard. Thanks again for sharing! Cheers.